# How get PHP single Array Value

Tags: php, json

How I can get only the value "RGE_NOMBRE" for fill an imput text in PHP  from the following array:

```
object(stdClass)#1367 (1) 
{
 ["GetContribuyentesResult"]=> string(161) "{"RGE_RUC":"102318239",**"RGE_NOMBRE"**:"P ARISTIDES HERNANDEZ C POR A","NOMBRE_COMERCIAL":"P ARISTIDES HERNANDEZ","CATEGORIA":"0","REGIMEN_PAGOS":"2","ESTATUS":"2"}" 
}
```

Comment: How does your input string look like? I assume you are doing a `json_decode` already to get a stdClass. Is that accurate?

Comment: I try convert to array using $data= (array) $response; and I am getting this format   {"RGE_RUC":"102318239","RGE_NOMBRE":"P ARISTIDES HERNANDEZ C POR A","NOMBRE_COMERCIAL":"P ARISTIDES HERNANDEZ","CATEGORIA":"0","REGIMEN_PAGOS":"2","ESTATUS":"2"}

Comment: How I can get only the ,"RGE_NOMBRE" to send to Input text?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please check Andrea's comment. It is difficult to guess like this. For example: what is `$response` How do you populate it? why are you trying to cast it to an array? Please post your codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your response is this:

```
{"RGE_RUC":"102318239","RGE_NOMBRE":"P ARISTIDES HERNANDEZ C POR A","NOMBRE_COMERCIAL":"P ARISTIDES HERNANDEZ","CATEGORIA":"0","REGIMEN_PAGOS":"2","ESTATUS":"2"}
```

what you have is a JSON object. To get what you want, decode the JSON and extract your data from the resulting object:

```
$jsonObject = json_decode($response);
$requiredData = $jsonObject->RGE_NOMBRE; ///  P ARISTIDES HERNANDEZ C POR A
```

Comment: I appreciate your help on that, I'm not pasted the full code because I'm working to integrate SoapResult in to Laravel :-), is an experiment..

Answer (score 0):

While your question is not very clear on how you get the string as a value of stdClass object with key `GetContribuyentesResult`, I am guess you are inserting the key later.

As per your comments you are doing `$data= (array) $response;` and your result is a string. Again this is not possible because you are trying to cast an array. Hence I assume `$response` is the string you are talking about.

This string is a `JSON` string about which you can read more on [this page](https://www.json.org/json-en.html).

And you can convert a json string to an array with [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) in php. This is how you can extract any key from a json string.

```
$response = '{"RGE_RUC":"102318239","RGE_NOMBRE":"P ARISTIDES HERNANDEZ C POR A","NOMBRE_COMERCIAL":"P ARISTIDES HERNANDEZ","CATEGORIA":"0","REGIMEN_PAGOS":"2","ESTATUS":"2"}';

# decoding to an associative array
$array = json_decode($response, true); ## or json_decode($response) to get an stdClass object
$requiredValue = $array['RGE_NOMBRE']; ## or $requiredValue = $array->RGE_NOMBRE; for stdClass object
```